# How to set a NAnt project's basedir to the current directory?

Tags: nant

I would like to use paths in multiple tasks without specifying the basedir attribute each time.

Unfortunately the following is not supported:

```
<project basedir="${directory::get-current-directory()}">
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

use (.) in like:

```
<project basedir=".">
</project>
```

so the basedir will be set to the directory of your build file.